# linq query issues with date type data

Tags: linq

I want to retrieve the data based on sku number like in below code,in this process i got all data same as it is in database but "date type" value is display like "01/01/0001".But i need to "date type" data like as it is in database date.any modifications i need to do .please help me out.

```
public IEnumerable<SKUDvo> getdatabysku()
{

    eshop_dbContext dbcontext123 = new eshop_dbContext();

    var productinfoQuery321 = (from productInfo321 in dbcontext123.ProductMasters
                               where productInfo321.SKU == "s121"
                               select productInfo321);

    IList<SKUDvo> productList123 = new List<SKUDvo>();
    foreach (var proitems in productinfoQuery321)
    {
        productList123.Add(new SKUDvo
        {
            skuno = name,
            ProductId = proitems.ProductId,
            CategoryID = proitems.CategoryID,
            ManufaturerId = proitems.ManufaturerId,
            ItemNo = proitems.ItemNo,
            ProductName = proitems.ProductName,
            DeletedInd = proitems.DeletedInd,
        });
    }
    return productList123;
}
```

My table is like below.

```
empid ename dateofjoin
10  sarath 26/02/2003
20  jai    16/03/2001
```

my result is like below

```
10 sarath 01/01/0001
20 jai    01/01/0001
```

Comment: In what way is your code related to the question?

Comment: Please include you data classes next time. However it looks like whilst you were mapping from you database objects to domain objects you forgot to map the date of join property. Hence it remains uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an  `DateTime` that hasn't been set. The default value of a `DateTime` is "01/01/0001 00:00:00".

```
// outputs the value of an empty DateTime: "01/01/0001 00:00:00"
Console.WriteLine(default(DateTime));
```

Are you sure that the `dateofjoin` is assigned? I don't see it in you code.